# .net core 1.0.0 with entity framework core sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I am trying to create a .net core application that has a connection to a sqlite database.

I have .net core sdk 1.0 installed and have added the following Nuget-packages to my project:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design

I am using the following project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": 
       {
      "version": "1.0.0-final",
      "imports": [ 
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I ran the following command:

```
dotnet restore
```

Now I want to check if the ef tool has been successfully installed to create a migration. But when I run:

```
dotnet ef --help
```

I get the following result:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App
  - The following versions are installed:
      1.0.0
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.0-rc2-3002702'.
```

Is it possible to installe release candidate 2 together with the 1.0 version and do I really have to do this to get entity framework runnging with .net core 1.0?

Comment: you have to update both to get to RTM status.  You can't mismatch versions.  Check that your Global.json file has the appropriate "sdk":{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this. The changes are based on https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/rc2-rtm-upgrade.html.

1. Change the version of the tools to 1.0.0-preview2-final
2. Remove the import in the frameworks section
3. Add a dependency to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design

Here is the complete project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": 
       {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [ 
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
    }
  }
}
```

and for completeness this is the global.json:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to update both to get to RTM.  You can't mismatch versions.  Check that your Global.json file has the appropriate 
`"sdk":{ "version" : "1.0.0-preview2-003121" }` is present.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The global.json has the correct version. But how can I update entity framework to RTM? According to Nuget I already have the latest version. Or do I just have to use a newer version of the entity framework tools?